# Divide image in array of images with swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, uiimage

I'm trying to divide an image to create 16 out of it (in a matrix). I'm using swift 2.1. Here's the code:

```
let cellSize = Int(originalImage.size.height) / 4

for i in 0...4 {
        for p in 0...4 {
            let tmpImgRef: CGImage = originalImage.CGImage!

            let rect: CGImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(CGFloat(i * cellSize), CGFloat(p * cellSize), CGFloat(cellSize), CGFloat(cellSize)))!

            gameCells.append(cell)

        }
    }
```

This works but the images that returns are only part of the original image. I've been searching and I know that's because when I create a CGImage it has a size different than the UIImage, but I don't know how to fix it. If I could make the variable cellSize with the height of the CGImage instead of the UIImage I suppose I would fix it but I can't get the CGImage height.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep, it has to be the scale, but it's a get-only properly, how can I consider it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fundamental issue is the difference between how `UIImage` and `CGImage` interpret their `size`. `UIImage` uses "points" and `CGImage` uses pixels. And the conversion factor is the [`scale`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiimage/1624110-scale).

For example, if a `UIImage` has a `scale` of 3, every "point" in any given direction the `UIImage`, there are three pixels in that direction in the underlying `CGImage`. So for a `UIImage` that has a `scale` of 3 and a `size` of 100x100 points, the underlying `CGImage` has a size of 300x300 pixels.

To return a simple array of images sliced by *n* x *n* (e.g. if *n* is three, there will be nine images in the array), you can do something like the following in Swift 3:

```
/// Slice image into array of tiles
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - image: The original image.
///   - howMany: How many rows/columns to slice the image up into.
///
/// - Returns: An array of images.
///
/// - Note: The order of the images that are returned will correspond
///         to the `imageOrientation` of the image. If the image's
///         `imageOrientation` is not `.up`, take care interpreting 
///         the order in which the tiled images are returned.

func slice(image: UIImage, into howMany: Int) -> [UIImage] {
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat

    switch image.imageOrientation {
    case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
        width = image.size.height
        height = image.size.width
    default:
        width = image.size.width
        height = image.size.height
    }

    let tileWidth = Int(width / CGFloat(howMany))
    let tileHeight = Int(height / CGFloat(howMany))

    let scale = Int(image.scale)
    var images = [UIImage]()

    let cgImage = image.cgImage!

    var adjustedHeight = tileHeight

    var y = 0
    for row in 0 ..< howMany {
        if row == (howMany - 1) {
            adjustedHeight = Int(height) - y
        }
        var adjustedWidth = tileWidth
        var x = 0
        for column in 0 ..< howMany {
            if column == (howMany - 1) {
                adjustedWidth = Int(width) - x
            }
            let origin = CGPoint(x: x * scale, y: y * scale)
            let size = CGSize(width: adjustedWidth * scale, height: adjustedHeight * scale)
            let tileCgImage = cgImage.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))!
            images.append(UIImage(cgImage: tileCgImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation))
            x += tileWidth
        }
        y += tileHeight
    }
    return images
}
```

Or, in Swift 2.3:

```
func slice(image image: UIImage, into howMany: Int) -> [UIImage] {
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat

    switch image.imageOrientation {
    case .Left, .LeftMirrored, .Right, .RightMirrored:
        width = image.size.height
        height = image.size.width
    default:
        width = image.size.width
        height = image.size.height
    }

    let tileWidth = Int(width / CGFloat(howMany))
    let tileHeight = Int(height / CGFloat(howMany))

    let scale = Int(image.scale)
    var images = [UIImage]()
    let cgImage = image.CGImage!

    var adjustedHeight = tileHeight

    var y = 0
    for row in 0 ..< howMany {
        if row == (howMany - 1) {
            adjustedHeight = Int(height) - y
        }
        var adjustedWidth = tileWidth
        var x = 0
        for column in 0 ..< howMany {
            if column == (howMany - 1) {
                adjustedWidth = Int(width) - x
            }
            let origin = CGPoint(x: x * scale, y: y * scale)
            let size = CGSize(width: adjustedWidth * scale, height: adjustedHeight * scale)
            let tileCgImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(cgImage, CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))!
            images.append(UIImage(CGImage: tileCgImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation))
            x += tileWidth
        }
        y += tileHeight
    }
    return images
}
```

This makes sure that the resulting images are in the correct `scale` (this is why the above strides through the image in "points" and the multiplies to get the correct pixels in the `CGImage`). This also, if the dimensions, measured in "points") are not evenly divisible by *n*, it will making up the difference in the last image for that row or column, respectively. E.g. when you make three tiles for an image with a height of 736 points, the first two will be 245 points, but the last one will be 246 points).

There is one exception that this does not (entirely) handle gracefully. Namely, if the `UIImage` has an `imageOrientation` of something other than `.up`, the order in which the images is retrieved corresponds to that orientation, not the upper left corner of the image as you view it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

you can split your image im two parts vertically and horizontally and sub split the result as needed:

```
extension UIImage {
    var topHalf: UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage, let image = cgImage.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: size.height/2))) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
    }
    var bottomHalf: UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage, let image = cgImage.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0,  y: CGFloat(Int(size.height)-Int(size.height/2))), size: CGSize(width: size.width, height: CGFloat(Int(size.height) - Int(size.height/2))))) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
    }
    var leftHalf: UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage, let image = cgImage.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: size.width/2, height: size.height))) else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
    }
    var rightHalf: UIImage? {
        guard let cgImage = cgImage, let image = cgImage.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(Int(size.width)-Int((size.width/2))), y: 0), size: CGSize(width: CGFloat(Int(size.width)-Int((size.width/2))), height: size.height)))
            else { return nil }
        return UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation)
    }
    var splitedInFourParts: [UIImage] {
        guard case let topHalf = topHalf,
              case let bottomHalf = bottomHalf,
            let topLeft = topHalf?.leftHalf,
            let topRight = topHalf?.rightHalf,
            let bottomLeft = bottomHalf?.leftHalf,
            let bottomRight = bottomHalf?.rightHalf else{ return [] }
        return [topLeft, topRight, bottomLeft, bottomRight]
    }
    var splitedInSixteenParts: [UIImage] {
        var array = splitedInFourParts.flatMap({$0.splitedInFourParts})
        // if you need it in reading order you need to swap some image positions
        swap(&array[2], &array[4])
        swap(&array[3], &array[5])
        swap(&array[10], &array[12])
        swap(&array[11], &array[13])
        return array
    }
}
```

---

Splitting the image by columns and rows:

```
extension UIImage {
    func matrix(_ rows: Int, _ columns: Int) -> [UIImage] {
        let y = (size.height / CGFloat(rows)).rounded()
        let x = (size.width / CGFloat(columns)).rounded()
        var images: [UIImage] = []
        images.reserveCapacity(rows * columns)
        guard let cgImage = cgImage else { return [] }
        (0..<rows).forEach { row in
            (0..<columns).forEach { column in
                var width = Int(x)
                var height = Int(y)
                if row == rows-1 && size.height.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: CGFloat(rows)) != 0 {
                    height = Int(size.height - size.height / CGFloat(rows) * (CGFloat(rows)-1))
                }
                if column == columns-1 && size.width.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: CGFloat(columns)) != 0 {
                    width = Int(size.width - (size.width / CGFloat(columns) * (CGFloat(columns)-1)))
                }
                if let image = cgImage.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: column * Int(x), y:  row * Int(x)), size: CGSize(width: width, height: height))) {
                    images.append(UIImage(cgImage: image, scale: scale, orientation: imageOrientation))
                }
            }
        }
        return images
    }
}
```

---

```
let myPicture = UIImage(data: try! Data(contentsOf: URL(string:"https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xs4RX.jpg")!))!

let images = myPicture.matrix(4, 4)

images.count   // 16
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I will probably need to slice it in a matrix of 5x5 and 6x6 in the future. I know I didn't write it in the main question, and I apology for it, I didn't think on this case

Answer (score 0):

I've used this to slice an image into a matrix. The matrix is represented as a 1D array.

```
func snapshotImage(image: UIImage, rect: CGRect) -> UIImage {
        var imageRect: CGRect! = rect

        if image.scale > 1.0 {
            imageRect = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: rect.origin.x * image.scale, y: rect.origin.y * image.scale), size: CGSize(width: rect.size.width * image.scale, height: rect.size.height * image.scale))
        }


        let imageRef: CGImage = image.cgImage!.cropping(to: imageRect)!
        let result: UIImage = UIImage(cgImage: imageRef, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation)
        return result
    }

    func sliceImage(image: UIImage, size: CGSize) -> [UIImage] {
        var slices: [UIImage] = [UIImage]()
        var rect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width, height: size.height)


        var y: Float = 0.0
        let width: Int = Int(image.size.width / size.width)
        let height: Int = Int(image.size.height / size.height)

        for _ in 0...height {
            var x: Float = 0.0

            for _ in 0...width {
                rect.origin.x = CGFloat(x);
                slices.append(self.snapshotImage(image: image, rect: rect))

                x += Float(size.width)
            }

            y += Float(size.height)
            rect.origin.y = CGFloat(y)
        }

        return slices
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. It gives me an error: "Value of type 'UIImage' has no member 'cgImage' " in the snapshot fun, when creating the imageRef.

Comment: Are you using Swift 2 or 3 ? Probably 2 I recommend you download the new (already old) Swift 3 from the AppStore Xcode 8.2.1

Comment: Ok, but what will happen with my code? Do I have to change it if I do it?

Comment: Yep, you'll have to go through a one time conversion. If you haven't already, I'd suggest watching the [WWDC 2016 videos](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc2016/). If you watch the Swift related videos, it will make your conversion process much, much easier. I'd keep a backup copy of your old project just in case. But you really should be using Swift 3. With the forthcoming Xcode 8.3, it's not going to support Swift 2.3 any more.

Comment: Ok, I'm on it, I will tell you when it's done. Thanks!