# How to use an UIImage array in Swift after dividing one image into multiple parts?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am following [this dicussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43008098/divide-image-in-array-of-images-with-swift) and got an array of images which are divided parts of the original image. If I print it, it looks like this:

```
[<UIImage: 0x61000008ea60>, {309, 212}, <UIImage: 0x61000008ec90>, {309, 212}, <UIImage: 0x61000008ebf0>, {309, 213}, <UIImage: 0x61000008ec40>, {309, 213}]
```

How could I use elements of this array? In the regular case I would have the name of the image and could use, for example, `UIImage(named: "")`. This array doesn't show me any names. Do you have any idea?

perhaps my mistake is here:

```
 func setImage(){


        testImage = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size/1.5, height: size/1.5))
        testImage.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.width/2, y: view.frame.height/2)


        slice(image: UIImage(named:"leopard_PNG14834")!, into: 8)

        testImage.image = images[2]


        view.addSubview(testImage)


}
```

Here is the function code

```
func slice(image: UIImage, into howMany: Int) -> [UIImage] {
    let width: CGFloat
    let height: CGFloat

    switch image.imageOrientation {
    case .left, .leftMirrored, .right, .rightMirrored:
        width = image.size.height
        height = image.size.width
    default:
        width = image.size.width
        height = image.size.height
    }

    let tileWidth = Int(width / CGFloat(howMany))
    let tileHeight = Int(height / CGFloat(howMany))

    let scale = Int(image.scale)


    let cgImage = image.cgImage!

    var adjustedHeight = tileHeight

    var y = 0
    for row in 0 ..< howMany {
        if row == (howMany - 1) {
            adjustedHeight = Int(height) - y
        }
        var adjustedWidth = tileWidth
        var x = 0
        for column in 0 ..< howMany {
            if column == (howMany - 1) {
                adjustedWidth = Int(width) - x
            }
            let origin = CGPoint(x: x * scale, y: y * scale)
            let size = CGSize(width: adjustedWidth * scale, height: adjustedHeight * scale)
            let tileCgImage = cgImage.cropping(to: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))!
            images.append(UIImage(cgImage: tileCgImage, scale: image.scale, orientation: image.imageOrientation))
            x += tileWidth
        }
        y += tileHeight
    }
    return images
}
```

Comment: Please give some more details. What do you want to do with the images? You can just access them by their index in the array btw.

Comment: Where is `size` being defined?

Comment: size = view.frame.width

Comment: Try testing your code with my advice in my answer and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're having a hard time adding your images to your ViewController, this is the common approach you would use to do so, assuming an input of an array of images:

```
let image = images[0]
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
self.view.addSubview(imageView)
```

**EDIT**

If you're messing with the frame of the image view, I would suggest doing it after you've initialized the UIImageView with an image like above. To test what's going on, perhaps just add an ImageView with your desired image without messing with the frame. Then check your variables that you are using to set the frame.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!

Comment: No worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You already get an array with objects of type `UIImage`.

```
let images = slice(image: someOriginalImage, into: 4)
let firstImage = images[0] // firstImage is a UIImage
```

`{309, 212}` is a size of the image.